# 13.10 samba installed. cannot find it revisited

Tags: samba

ok trying again, and putting a different way..

*i have installed 13.10
*i would like to enable Personal File Sharing
*the 'share files over the network' section is greyed out and says "this feature cannot be enabled because the required packages are not installed on your system".
i believe that is a reference to nautilus or samba or both.  both of these are installed but i still cannot enable personal file sharing
*when i look in the software centre it says Samba is installed, but when i look through the Applications menus, i cannot find it anywhere. i have gone to the Main Menu and enabled absolutely everything, yet i still cannot open Samba to configure it.

QUESTIONS:
*why cannot i not find Samba in the applications list?  i can on my older Ubuntu version (12 something) on my pc
*is there something else i need to install to make personal file sharing work?

thanks

Comment: Run 'sudo apt-get install samba' in a terminal and see what you get. Then run 'sudo system-config-samba' to configure Samba.

Answer (score 2):

A late response: I think Samba is not an application but it is a system service. That's probably why you can not find it on the application list.

Try

```
apt-cache policy samba
```

to check if it is installed. You should see someting like:

```
samba:
  Installed: 2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.11
```

If it is not installed, install it.
If it is installed, try

```
ps aux | grep nmbd
```

to see if the service running. You should get something like:

```
root         1910  0.0  0.0  91268  1988 ?        Ss   21:06   0:00 nmbd -D
username     5962  0.0  0.0  14952   968 pts/2    S+   23:11   0:00 grep --color=auto nmbd
```

If you don't get one of these lines, then try to stop and restart the service:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for the distinction between application and system services